# Sass is not found for gulp-ruby-sass within Docker container

Tags: docker, sass, rubygems, gulp-ruby-sass

I have a web application that uses the `gulp-ruby-sass` plugin and it runs within a container that installs the `sass` gem.

This is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM phusion/passenger-customizable:0.9.19
# Set correct environment variables.
ENV HOME /root
# Use baseimage-docker's init process.
CMD ["/sbin/my_init"]
#   Build system and git.
RUN /pd_build/utilities.sh && \
#   Ruby support.
    /pd_build/ruby-2.3.*.sh && \
#   Node.js and Meteor support.
    /pd_build/nodejs.sh && \
    npm install -g gulp jspm yarn && \
        npm install phantomjs-prebuilt@2.1.9 && \
        mv node_modules/phantomjs-prebuilt/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs /usr/bin && \
        rm -r node_modules && \
#   Clean up APT when done.
    apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*
EXPOSE 9000
WORKDIR /var/www/
CMD /bin/bash
```

This is the bootstrap script file (to bootstrap the application):

```
#! /bin/bash

bundle install
npm install
jspm install
npm config set bin-links false
npm rebuild node-sass

gulp watch
```

This is the Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"

gem "sass"
```

And I launch the container this way:

```
docker run -it --name web -p 9000:9000 --volume $(pwd):/var/www brainy_web sh bootstrap.sh
```

The problem is that when the gulp task `gulp build-css` is executed using `docker-compose`, it doesn't find the `sass` gem as it is shown in the log: `Gem sass is not installed` (complete log [here](https://gist.github.com/paolocarrasco/9137392ecb2beb558070bd7e8e96c81b)), but when I run the container with bash and execute the `bootstrap.sh` file everything runs smoothly.

Any thoughts on how to use `sass` with `docker` and `gulp-ruby-sass`?

**UPDATE**

I found that executing from the outside the gulp task, it doesn't find either:

```
docker exec web gulp build-css
```

Comment: have you tried this instead?
 docker run -it --name web -p 9000:9000 --volume $(pwd):/var/www brainy_web bash bootstrap.sh

Comment: it looked promising... but I tried and it's returning the same message (Gem sass is not installed)

Comment: I'm guessing it is related with environment variables that are not available... I'm going to take a look at the gulp-ruby-sass plugin.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought too. That's way I suggested bash instead of sh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution! I followed the advice from @webert-s-lima and in here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29999734/532912
I just added the `-l` argument when launching the container. The statement would be like this:

```
docker run -it --name web -p 9000:9000 --volume $(pwd):/var/www brainy_web /bin/bash -l bootstrap.sh
```